# Understanding templates with/in printSeq implementation (... class = allocator ...)

Tags: c++, templates, stl

I am learning templates in C++. (what I know is what I got from reading Part 1 and 2 of [this survey](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/268849/An-Idiots-Guide-to-Cplusplus-Templates-Part))

Haven't read much about the containers in STL. But that is coming next in my list.

I am trying to understand the following definition of a template function to print the elements of a sequence.

```
 template<class T, template<class U, class = allocator<U>> class Seq>
 void printSeq(Seq<T>& seq) {
    for (typename Seq<T>::iterator b = seq.begin(); b != seq.end();)
        cout << *b++ << endl;
 };
```

My problem is in the first line. What I think I understand:

1. There is the template clause `template< type1 , type2 >`. The `type1` is `class T`, a class that is going to be identified with the name `T` in the rest of the definition.
2. The `type2` is `template<class U, class = allocator<U>> class Seq`.
3. This `type2` is also a template class. This is why they use `template<...> class Seq`.
4. In `template<class U, class = allocator<U>>` we have again the form `template< type 3, type4>`. Here `type3` is `class U`, a class to be identified with the name `U`.

The part I don't understand is `class = allocator<U>`. I suppose the compiler will know first the actual type for `U`, with it it can 'instantiate' (is this the right term?) the template `allocator` to get a type `allocator<U>` (!?). But there is the `=`.

**Questions:**

1. Is it correct that `= allocator<U>` will be returning a type?
2. How is the `=` working in this construction?
3. My problem seems to be more about `allocator`. Where can I read about what I am missing? I was reading [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Allocator) but still I don't understand the role of the `=`.

Comment: `Seq` is a template template argument, and the `= allocator<U>` supplies a default template argument, so that when you write `Seq<T>` it's really `Seq<T, allocator<T>>`. That's definitely *not* how I would write the function, though.

Comment: @T.C. OH!!! It is just the same as if they had written `template<class U, class V = allocator<U>> class Seq`. I just tried and it compiles and runs. I missed the fact that you could skip the name `V` in the template parameter.

Comment: I just checked in the survey I read about templates they didn't mention that possibility of skipping the identifier in a default template parameter. Thanks.